# What is the most likely cause for FF and Chrome breaking a layout?

Tags: wordpress, cross-browser, cross-platform

## The problem

I've come across a "featured articles" section of a WordPress driven website the renders as expected in the current versions Opera, Safari and IE6+ but breaks in the current versions of Chrome and FF.

## The website

The website can be viewed [here](http://www.cagepotato.com). The "featured article" section is visible at the top of the home page.

## What I've tried

I've used firebug and screened the code through the W3C validation. Though there are numerous errors nothing jumps out at me as the cause.

## Additional information

I've been told that the code renders consistently across all browsers on a Mac but not on PC's.

## What I need

Though I do not represent the website nor am I working on it I simply want to understand why the cross-browser issue is occurring.

Comment: What is broken? Looks exactly the same to me in Chrome 12 and IE9.

Comment: The correctly rendered code will display a large thumbnail stacked on top of three smaller thumbnails. The broken layout simply stacks the four thumbnails vertically. Did you read what I mentioned under "Additional Information" in my post? Is your computer a Mac by any chance?

Comment: Yeah, Chrome 12 on PC. Looks totally fine. One big image with batman and robin and then three images horizontally aligned below it.

Comment: That's odd. We're using the same browser, each of us on a PC and yet we're producing different different results. I should have additionally asked if you're using Windows 7. If not, by process of elimination, it would seem that OS is the issue.

Comment: Three different Windows 7 computers and they all render the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the page isn't valid then a browser will try its best to fix it before rendering. In chrome you can view console output and it can tell you how it chose to fix problems. It really isn't worth investigating the why as each browser's development team will choose to solve problems in different ways. Now if the page is valid and they render differently it would be useful to know why.

Comment: Cheers for the insight. Is invalid code rendered in quirks mode or would that just be for absent doctypes?

Comment: Quirksmode.org goes into excruciating detail. But the general rule is that the doctype is used to determine strict mode. If no doctype is specified then strict is assumed. Then there are exceptions to the rule. And then of course exceptions to the exceptions. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: Cheers for the explanation though based on mrtsherman's feedback, do you have any idea why the code would render differently on two PC's with the same browser version? I've yet to establish whether or not mrtsherman and I are using the same OS.